# Move to next textbox when 'Enter' key is pressed instead of submit (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a simple form and I would like that when the user presses enter in his phone keyboard the cursor will move to the next textbox.
Can this be done in Universal Windows Apps?
In android the keyboard shows a Next/Done key to navigate in the form elements.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use FocusManager to move the focus programmatically.

Use the KeyDown event of the TextBox container, let's say, a StackPanel, to listen to your keyboard event. So your code would work like this way

```
    private void stackPanel_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() == inputTextBox) // Change the inputTextBox to your TextBox name
            {
                FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
                FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
            }
            else
            { 
                FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
            }

            // Make sure to set the Handled to true, otherwise the RoutedEvent might fire twice
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

For more details on FocusManager, see to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.focusmanager.trymovefocus

For more details on KeyDown, see to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keydown

Comment: The only thing that is still troubling me is, why do you assign it to the StackPanel instead of the textbox like: `<TextBox KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>`

Comment: So there is only the enter button and no done/next buttons?

Answer (score 0):

do you have something like `yourTextBoxName.Focus()` ..? also use the KeyDownEvent for the `New Password` textbox and check the following

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.PlatformKeyCode == 0x0A)
{
     confirmPassword.Focus();//change confirmPassword to your controls actual name    
}
```